# Cannot connect to DocumentDb directly after having deployed the DocumentDb account

Tags: azure, templates, deployment, azure-cosmosdb, azure-resource-manager

I have an ARM template that I use to deploy a DocumentDB as well as other Azure reosurces to a resource group. I want my ARM template to setup a Stream Analytics job that uses the DocumentDB as output. In order to do this the DocumentDB account created by the ARM template needs to have a database and a collection setup as well. I cannot find a way to do this from an ARM template so I have written a Powershell CmdLet to create the database and collction for me.

The Stream Analytics job cannot be created by the first ARM template since it depends on having the database and collection created first. Instead I have to divide the deployment into two ARM templates, the first setting up the DocDb account and the second setting up the SA job.

The problem is that I cannot create a database in the DocDB account directly after having deployed the account via the ARM template. I get an exception with the following message: "The remote name could not be resolved: 'test.documents.azure.com'" when I try to execute the CreateDatabaseAsync method with the DocDbEndpoint and AuthKey I get back from the ARM template deployment.

Are there any timing issues after having deployed Azure resources using a ARM template before you can access them programatically? This do not seem to be a problem with other Azure reosurces created this way.

Any help on this matter is highly appreciated as well as what is a good practice for working with ARM templates with DocumentDB and Stream Analytic jobs.

**Update 2016-03-23**

Code for setting up the connection to the DocumentDB to create the database.

```
Uri endpointUri = new Uri(documentDbEndPoint);
DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(endpointUri, authKey);
var db = await client.CreateDatabaseAsync(new Database { Id = databaseId });
return db;
```

Where the documentDbEndPoint is in the form of: https://name.documents.azure.com:443/ and *name* is the name of my DocDB account just created by the ARM template deployment.

I have the code in a library which I can either call from a Console application or from a Powershell script by loading the library with:

`Add-Type -Path <path to library dll file>`

No matter if I use powershell or console application I get the same error if I try to create a database just after having created the DocDB account using the ARM template. If I wait like an hour or so both the powershell script and console application works and can create a database in the account.

Seems like there is some kind of timing issue in order for Azure to setup dns records for the newly created DocDB account so that it can be accessed using the DocDB API.

**Update 2 2016-03-23**
Just tried to create a DocDB account directly from the portal and doing this instead of creating it from an ARM template makes it possible to create a database in the account using my powershell script and console application immediately.

Comment: Could you post the detailed code for the connection? Sounds like something wrong with the Endpoint URI.

Answer (score 0):

This timing issue has been fixed now and you should be able to use it from the ARM template now.